# SQLite query not returning expected results despite correct hashing and comparison in Android application

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, blob

I'm facing an issue with comparing a hashed email value stored as a BLOB in an SQLite database with a hash generated from an email address in my Android application. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
public UserCredentials findUserCredentials(String email) throws DBFindException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    UserCredentials userCredentials = null;

    try {
        db = open();
        byte[] emailHash = SecurityService.hash(SerializationUtils.serialize(email));

        String selection = EMAIL_HASH + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {new String(emailHash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)};
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] passwordBytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(PASSWORD));
            byte[] salt = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(PASSWORD_SALT));
            if (passwordBytes != null && salt != null) {
                HashData hashData = new HashData(passwordBytes, salt);
                userCredentials = new UserCredentials(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)), hashData);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException | SerializationException | HashException exception) {
        throw new DBFindException("Failed to findUserCredentials from user with email (" + email + ")", exception);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
        close(db);
    }

    return userCredentials;
}
```

Despite ensuring that the hash generated from the email address matches the value stored in the database, the query doesn't return any results. I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm passing the hashed value as an argument in the selectionArgs. However, even after converting the hash to hexadecimal format for comparison, the problem persists.

Could someone please advise on what might be causing this issue or suggest any potential solutions?

PS: This is the code snippet I'm using for 'getContentValues during the insert operation, where EMAIL_HASH is a column in the database and user.getEmail() returns a String:

contentValues.put(EMAIL_HASH, SecurityService.hash(SerializationUtils.serialize(user.getEmail())));

Comment: `new String(emailHash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is probably not the correct way to create a hash string. `emailHash` is a `byte[]`. To convert that to a string, you should encode this as base64 or hex. Just converting each byte to UTF-8 will probably produce some unprintable characters ...

Comment: I tried to convert the email hash to hex but it doesn't match with the column of type BLOB. I tried extracting the BLOB with cursor.getBlob to compare the values manually and they are the same hash. The problem is to pass the emailHash as a selectionArgs. How should I do that? Like I said Hex doesn't match.

Comment: I'd not store any hash as blob but as hex or base64 string.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll do that. I saw other options but they are not worth the time. I think just having a TEXT column for hash will simplify all a lot.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106519/how-to-search-for-a-specific-blob-in-sqlite/54111072#54111072

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you're using the same hashing algorithm and encoding/decoding mechanisms when generating and comparing the hashed values. Any discrepancy in the hashing process can lead to mismatched values.

Here's a modified version of your code snippet that demonstrates how you can encode the hashed values as hexadecimal strings:

```
String emailHashHex = bytesToHex(emailHash); // Convert byte array to hexadecimal string

String selection = EMAIL_HASH + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = { emailHashHex };

// Helper method to convert byte array to hexadecimal string
private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

By ensuring consistent encoding and decoding mechanisms and using hexadecimal encoding for comparison, you should be able to compare the hashed values successfully in your SQLite query.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is that I would like to compare BLOB type values. I finally used base64 to convert from byte[] to String and changed the EMAIL_HASH column of the SQLite database to type TEXT instead of BLOB. This uses more space but it works. I saw a way to compare BLOB type values overriding internal cursor classes, but it wasn't worth the time coding.